# How to play order of cards and triggering effects in Harry Potter Defense Against the Dark Arts

Tags: harry-potter-hogwarts-battle

This question is for the 2 player Harry Potter Defense Against the Dark Arts dueling game and not the 4 play cooperative game.  It wouldn't let me add the new label for the dueling game.

How do we process the effects of additional cards we draw?

Meaning, do I need to be strategic with the order of how I play my cards or can I retroactively change my actions based on subsequent cards I draw.

For example, if I have these 5 cards.

1. Alohomora  -  Spell  Gain 1 coin
2. Diffindo  -  Spell Banish a card from my hand or discard pile
3. Wand  -  Item Gain a lightning bolt
4. Book  -  Item Gain 2 coins
5. Ascendio  -  Spell  Gain 2 coin/ Draw a Card

A) I use Diffindo to banish the Alohomora
B) I get a lightning bolt from Wand
C) I get 2 coins from Book
D) I get 2 more coins from Ascendio and draw an extra card
E6) Cat  -  (Drawn from Ascendio)  Ally.  If we play 3 spells, we gain a lightning bolt

I play my Cat as my Ally but I now take back banishing the Alohomora because I want to utilize the Cat ability to get another lightning bolt.

Is what I did legal, take back banishing the Alohomora because I drew the Cat?  If it's illegal, I guess that means I need to be more strategic when playing my cards.

Comment: "Take backs" are generally not handled by the rules and are more of a social question: how does your group play? If your group plays loose with the rules, they may allow take backs.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally no, it's not allowed.**

Once a card's effect has taken place, you can't reverse the decision. As L. Scott Johnson aluded to in his comment, this is something that friends at the table can allow, especially if the outcome hasn't changed because of something that was triggered by the effect.

For example, if you banish a coin to draw another card, and receive another coin. If you had kept the first coin and banished something else you could now have afforded buying a new card so you want to change your mind about what you banish. At this point you've cheated by looking at what will happen in the future depending on what you decide to banish. That's like looking at the top card before deciding what you want to do.

In your example however it more comes down to a gentlemans agreement since the card you banished doesn't affect what you were allowed to do while it was in play. So I wouldn't be surprised if your opponent allows it if you ask.

I would personally however say that this is a good lesson in tactics and use it to learn how to plan what you need to do in a turn to minimize mistakes like this.